# How to show a number on a widget when i execute OnUpdate

Tags: android, android-widget

i've actuallay made a widget for my application.
This application use a database.
What i try to do:
 - I can now how much count have a table in my database, i wich show this number on my widget, is it possible?

For the moment, in my onUpdate function, i count my number of record, but how to show this?

Thanks by advance.

regards.

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have a `TextView` with a unique ID in the layout of your widget.  Then in your `onUpdate` method have somthing like:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    String countValue = "0";
    // code to retrieve & populate the count value goes here

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetData, countValue);
    for (int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++){
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
    }
}
```